# How to set magnitude and direction in a ZxZ grid

Tags: python

I'm working through a problem (using python) that asks me to do the following:

Starting from (0,0) and facing North in a \mathbb{Z} x \mathbb{Z} grid, and given a sequence of 'moves' (R for right, L for left, and F for forward by 1), what will be the final position of a particle assuming we can only move by 1's in the horizontal and vertical directions. For example, moves = 'RFRL' will put us at (1,0)

The difficulty I am having on getting started with this problem is that I don't know how to represent a "turn". An 'F' in the 'moves' will mean adding +-1 to the y coordinate depending if the particle is facing North or South, and +-1 to the x coordinate depending if the particle is facing East or West.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to split the task into subtasks. You need to implement an operation of turning, and operation of going forward, with respect to where you're currently facing. For example, you can do like this.

```py
def turn_right(current_direction):
    next_direction_map = {'N':'E', 'E':'S', 'S':'W', 'W':'N'}
    return next_direction_map[current_direction]

def turn_left(current_direction):
    next_direction_map =  {'N':'W', 'W':'S', 'S':'E', 'E':'N'}
    return next_direction_map[current_direction]    

def forward(current_position, current_direction):
    x, y = current_position
    if current_direction == 'N':
        return (x, y+1)
    elif current_direction == 'S':
        return (x, y-1)
    elif current_direction == 'E':
        return (x+1, y)
    elif current_direction == 'W':
        return (x-1, y)

facing_direction = 'N'
current_position = (0, 0)
facing_direction = turn_right(facing_direction)
current_position = forward(current_position, facing_direction)
facing_direction = turn_right(facing_direction)
facing_direction = turn_left(facing_direction)

print(current_position, facing_direction)
```

Notice that using a dictionary I can tell with just 1 line where I'll be turning. A similar dictionary approach could be used in `forward` function too, but I'm afraid it would look scary (with `lambdas` stored inside the dictionary).

Now you're only left with reading the path string (`RFRL`), iterating over it with a loop, and calling an appropriate method on the current facing direction and current position. This I left for you (for educational purposes)